# Variable undefined in JavaScript Learn Mate Academy

Tags: variables, undefined

i am a complete programming beginner, and would appreciate your help with a simple task:

Let's declare a few variables with some values ​​inside:

```
variable brand with a value 'Toyota'
variable price with a value 22500
variable isSedan with a value true
variable wings with a value undefined
variable owner with a value null
```

Note: use the const keyword to declare variables.

I cannot get the code right, can someone please help?? Thanks to anyone willing to help a noob learning something completely from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare variables with const like this:
const (name) = (value)

```
const brand = 'Toyota';
const price = 22500;
const isSedan = true;
const wings = undefined;
const owner = null;
```